# What is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{f(n)}\right)^{2f(n)}$ when $f(n)$ grows faster than $n$?

Tags: limits

What is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{f(n)}\right)^{2f(n)}$$ when $f(n)$ grows faster than $n$? Is the limit $1$?

How fast should $f(n)$ grow for this to happen?

Comment: Have you tried $f(n)=n\log n$?

Comment: $f(n)=n^{1+\epsilon}$ should suffice but sometimes wolfram alpha confuses me by throwing out $0$ that is why this problem

Comment: you will often be confused by using wolfram

Comment: limits don't converge; they either exist or they don't

Comment: @zhw. ok............................. do you have other such oddities from wolfram?

Comment: @Turbo The question that bugs me... where does that strange expression come from in the first place?

Comment: @ClementC. what is strange about this?

Comment: @Turbo Nothing per se... it just doesn't seem like the first expression I'd think about on my spare time, so I was curious about whether it originated from some particular context.

Comment: @ClementC. from a cs theory problem

Comment: @Turbo ack. Thanks!

Comment: @ClementC. only in theory we get such strange items. what does **tl;dr:** mean?

Comment: "Too long; didn't read." It's commonly used to introduce a summary or condensed version of something much longer that follows.

Comment: @ClementC. I saw something in hamiltonian cycles somewhere it gives something like this (may be dirichlet's theorem?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** the limit could be anything in $[0,1]$.

Let $f$ be a function of the form
$$
f(n) = n g(n)
$$
with $g(n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$. Then we can write
$$
\left(1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{f(n)}\right)^{2f(n)}
= e^{ 2f(n) \ln \left(1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{f(n)}\right) }
= e^{ 2n g(n) \ln \left(1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n g(n)}\right) }.
$$
Let's break it down.
$$
\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n g(n)}
= e^{g(n)\cdot n \ln\left(1-\frac1n\right) }
= e^{g(n) (-1+o(1)) } \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$
since $g(n)\to\infty$. Therefore, we can use the Taylor expansion of $\ln$ to get:
$$
2n g(n) \ln \left(1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n g(n)}\right)
= - 2n g(n) \left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n g(n)}
= - 2n g(n)e^{-g(n) (1+o(1)) }
$$
This gives us some intuition. This can go, depending on $g(n)$, to either $0$, $-\infty$, or basically any constant $c<0$.

For instance, take

- $g(n) = \ln n$: then $- 2n g(n)e^{-g(n) (1+o(1)) } = -2(1+o(1))\ln n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} -\infty$, and the overall limit will be $0$. (After taking the exponential).
- $g(n) = 2\ln n$: then $- 2n g(n)e^{-g(n) (1+o(1)) } = -2(1+o(1))\frac{\ln n}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, and the overall limit will be $e^0=1$.
- $g(n) = \ln n + \ln \ln n$: then one can [check](http://goo.gl/OeBNKq) (being a bit more careful in the above, that is in the $o(1)$ term) that $2n g(n) \ln \left(1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n g(n)}\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} -2$, and the overall limit will be $e^{-2}$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the above "$c [...]$ we have [...]." If the quantity $2n g(n) \ln \left(1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n g(n)}\right)$ converges to $c$, then the original quantity converges to $e^c$.

Comment: $\alpha\in(0,1]$ and $g(n)=\alpha\ln n$ we have $-2ng(n)e^{-g(n)(1+o(1))}\rightarrow-\infty$ and $\alpha\in(1,\infty]$ and $g(n)=\alpha\ln n$ we have $-2ng(n)e^{-g(n)(1+o(1))}\rightarrow0$. How do you get any constant (I see $e^{-2}$ but its not clear).

Comment: Consider $g(n)=\alpha\ln n +\beta\ln\ln n$ where $\alpha,\beta>0$ then what do we get?

Comment: I do not see how $2n g(n)\ln\left(1-\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n g(n)}\right)$ can converge to any desired $c>0$. I see only $-\infty$, $-2$ and $0$.

Comment: @Turbo [Try with $g(n) = \ln n + \ln\ln n +a$ for any constant $a$ of your choosing.](http://goo.gl/zKZrHn). The limit will be $-e^{-a}$.

Comment: Well done! +1...

Comment: how do you add such inks in comments?

Comment: @Turbo: not really the topic here, but [the text](the link) is the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is to take a logarithm of the expression you need to find the limit of:
$$
2 f(n) \ln \left[
1 - \left( 1 - {1 \over n} \right)^{f(n)}
\right].
$$
We now want to estimate (the existence of) the limit of 
$$
\left( 1 - {1 \over n} \right)^{f(n)}.
$$
Write
$$
\left( 1 - {1 \over n} \right)^{f(n)} = 
\left\{
\left( 1 - {1 \over n} \right)^{n}
\right\}^{f(n)/n}
$$
and take the logarithm once again:
$$
({f(n)/n}) \ln \left\{
\left( 1 - {1 \over n} \right)^{n}
\right\}
$$
As $n \rightarrow \infty$, the latter logarithm tends to a definite limit (-1), and the ratio $({f(n)/n})$ to infinity (since we are told that $f(n)$ grows faster than $n$.

Comment: You forget to then undo taking the logarithm. You need to place your answer into e^x in order to undo your calculation.

Comment: I don't forget.:)  I just gave some of the process, hoping to get the Asker started.

Comment: Once you have the limit of $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{f(n)}$ (it's $0$), this still doesn't say anything about the limit of the whole expression, though -- it still could be (almost) anything.

Comment: Should have thought it through, but didn't have time.  All I wanted was to indicate to use the interplay between the logarithm and the exponential.  Should have limited myself to that.

Comment: @avs Agreed about the "interplay" -- that definitely the natural thing to start with!